celery task is recieved but is not executed
Here is main2.py where i have used a model from huggingface
import requests
from PIL import Image
from celery import Celery
import time

from transformers import BlipProcessor, BlipForConditionalGeneration
processor = BlipProcessor.from_pretrained("Salesforce/blip-image-captioning-base")
model = BlipForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("Salesforce/blip-image-captioning-base")

celery_app = Celery('main2', broker='redis://localhost:6379', backend='redis://localhost:6379')
@celery_app.task
def get_image_inference(img_url):
    raw_image = Image.open(requests.get(img_url, stream=True).raw).convert('RGB')

    inputs = processor(raw_image, return_tensors="pt")
    out = model.generate(**inputs)
    x = processor.decode(out[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
    result = {"caption": str(x)}  # Store the string result of x in a dict where key is "caption"
    return result


if __name__=="__main__":
    x = get_image_inference("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSQk254vG59DJjjefU3Lxgt-0RBBTGi-DVGxE9_ptgC5g&s")
    print(x)

here is main3.py
from main2 import get_image_inference


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url_ = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSQk254vG59DJjjefU3Lxgt-0RBBTGi-DVGxE9_ptgC5g&s"
    result = get_image_inference.delay(url_)
    print(result.get())

and here is
celery -A main2 worker -l info



 -------------- celery@developmentgpu3 v5.4.0 (opalescent)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.15.0-105-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35 2024-05-23 19:38:06
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         main2:0x7f826060e1d0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 72 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
  . main2.get_image_inference

[2024-05-23 19:38:15,946: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/developmentgpu3/RaheemTariq/celeryy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py:508: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
  warnings.warn(

[2024-05-23 19:38:15,952: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379//
[2024-05-23 19:38:15,953: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/developmentgpu3/RaheemTariq/celeryy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py:508: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
  warnings.warn(

[2024-05-23 19:38:15,954: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2024-05-23 19:38:16,962: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2024-05-23 19:38:16,976: INFO/MainProcess] celery@developmentgpu3 ready.
[2024-05-23 19:40:33,113: INFO/MainProcess] Task main2.get_image_inference[0e342548-3e1d-4b5b-b9bf-a3d7a7f4ac1f] received


i have executed main2.py alone and the model is working file but when i execute main3.py celery recieves the task but never executes it
i require assistance with the solution and do tell me where am i going wrong and how to fix it thank youu
